# Двойная кавычка как значение символьной переменной

Tags: c++

Требуется вычистить строку от знаков препинания. Для этого я написал такую функцию:

```
wstring clearstr (wstring str){
  wchar_t arr[] = {',','.','-',':',';','?','!',')','(','\"'};
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
      int n = str.size();
      if (n==1&&str[0]==arr[i]) return L"";
      //wcout << str.size() << L" ";
      if (str[0]==arr[i]) str.erase(str[0]);
      //wcout << str[n-1] << endl;
      if (str[n-1]==arr[i]) str.erase(str.begin()+n-1);
      //wcout << str << endl;
  }
  return str;
}
```

Так вот, если массив `arr[]` содержит кавычку (как здесь) - вылетает ошибка `out_of_range`, а при дебаггинге с отладочной печатью (закомментированные строки) выясняется, что кавычка и не удалялась:

```
9 "Кораблик
```

Без кавычки всё нормально работает. В чём причина?

upd: полный вывод из консоли:

```
9 к //9 - кол-во символов, к - последний символ
//удаляем запятую
"Кораблик //запятой нет
//удаляем точку
9 к
"Кораблик //точки нет
//удаляем дефис
9 к
"Кораблик //дефиса нет
//удаляем двоеточие
9 к
"Кораблик //двоеточия нет
//удаляем точку с запятой
9 к
"Кораблик //точки с запятой нет
//удаляем вопросительный знак
9 к
"Кораблик //вопросительного знака нет
//удаляем восклицательный знак
9 к
"Кораблик //восклицательного знака нет
//удаляем закр. скобку
9 к
"Кораблик //закр. скобки нет
//удаляем откр. скобку
9 к
"Кораблик //откр. скобки нет
//удаляем кавычку
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::erase: __pos (which is 34) > this->size() (which is 9)
9 Аварийный останов (сделан дамп памяти) //WTF?
```

Comment: Вы проверяете, что в если в переданной строке в конце или в начале стоит один из элементов arr. Если есть то обрезаете, иначе ничего не делаете. Как вы хотите "добраться" до кавычки в середине строки?

Comment: Где вы видели там кавычку в середине строки? Если вы про `9 "Кораблик`, то там 9 - это кол-во символов в строке.

Comment: @Byulent  Совершенно не понятно, что вы пытаетесь сделать. Вы хотите удалить только первый и последний символ из строки, если они соответствуют знаку препинания, или же вы хотите удалить все знаки препинания из строки?

Comment: @Byulent, приведите пример входной и выходной строк

Comment: @Grundy, `водой.` => `водой`, `(вернее` => `вернее`. А на строке с кавычкой он застревает.

Comment: а примера с кавычкой так и не привели :-)

Comment: @Grundy, `"Кораблик` же.

Comment: ага, поправьте в посте `9 "Кораблик` без пояснений в комментариях непонятно что это значит

Comment: @Byulent, поставьте вместо кавычки, точку. Тесть сделайте строку ".Кораблик". Ваша программа сломается на втором проходе по циклу. Если же вы поставите точку после слова, то ваша программа обрежет точку без проблем. Вы по-разному обращаетесь к функции erase. В первом случае передаете символ. Во втором номер символа.

Comment: @SanekZhitnik, всё, понял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для функции [erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) используйте номер элемента в строке.

```
str.erase(n, m);//Удалит все что между n и m
str.erase(n);//Удалит все что после n
```

Ваши два последних условия можно заменить на следующий код. Он будет работать только при условии, что вы разбираете строку по словам.

```
if (str[0] == arr[i]) {
    str.erase(0, 1);
    n = str.size();
}
if (str[n - 1] == arr[i]) str.erase(n - 1);
```

---

Пример:

```
wstring clearstr (wstring str){
wchar_t arr[] = {',','.','-',':',';','?','!',')','(','\"'};

for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    int n = str.size();
    if (n==1&&str[0]==arr[i]) return L"";
    //wcout << str.size() << L" ";
    if (str[0] == arr[i]) {
        str.erase(0, 1);
        n = str.size();
    }
    if (str[n - 1] == arr[i]) str.erase(n - 1);
    //wcout << str << endl;
}
return str;
}
int main() {

    std::wstring w= L"\"Hello.world\"?";
    std::wstring w2 = clearstr(w);
    wcout<<w2;
    return 0;
}
```

Данный код вернет следующую строку:

```
Hello.world
```

Comment: И как это мне поможет?

Comment: @Byulent, может быть связано с тем, что кавычки бывают разные `"`, `<<` (не знаю как вставить "русскую" кавычку? Выведите в консоль символ кавычки в виде кода из строки, которая не обрабатывается.

Comment: @andy.37, вы думаете, я не смотрю на текст, который нужно обработать? Смотрю, и кавычка там именно вот такая : `"`.

Comment: @Byulent, в любом случае проверьте код символа в массиве и в строке - очень многие символы выглядят одинаково, но имеют разный код

Comment: @Byulent, Юникодовский код выводили? Может в консоли выглядеть одинаково, а коды разные. Кстати, Ваш алгоритм по разному обработает строки `.,string` и `,.string`.

Comment: @Byulent, ошибка возникает во время выполнений вот это строки:     str.erase(str[0]);

Comment: @SanekZhitnik, почему же тогда с другими символами всё работает?

Comment: @Byulent, строка ",Hello.world\"?" в первом же проходе по циклу прервала процесс.